# Displaying and manipulating worksheet table selections on Excel UserForm

Tags: userform

I would like to be able to make table selections on a worksheet from within a VBA UserForm in ListView. In addition to this, I would also need to be able to save these selections to a separate sheet.

I have several worksheets, all of which have 9 columns. In column 1 of table1 different breeds of dogs are being displayed. Column 2 shows their age, column 3 their colour, etc. I can make these selections on the worksheet, but would like to be able to do this on an Excel UserForm, displaying these selections in ListView and save it to a separate sheet. How can I do this?

I have tried the following code:

```
Private Sub_Initialize()

Dim tbl As Listbox
Set tbl= Activesheet.ListObjects("Table1")

Combobox1.List = tbl.ListColumns(9).DataBodyRange.Value

End Sub
```

This results in `runtime error 13(type mismatch)`. I am kinda stuck at that.